# What is the default psi function for the rlm (robust regression) function?

Tags: r, regression, function, rlm

What is the default psi function for the rlm (robust regression) function from MASS package? Is it a bisquare function? If not, may I know what psi function it gives out by default if I do not specify anything except the y~x formula in it?

Comment: This is covered quite clearly in the help on the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The default](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/rlm.html) `psi` is `psi.huber`. You can run the bisquare by specifying `psi=psi.bisquare`.

Comment: Thank you so much. If you don't mind, may I know the mathematical expression for the psi.huber used in this function?

Answer (score 3):

Mark White is correct, but if you specify the popular `method = 'MM'` option, the default will be `psi = psi.bisquare`.  In fact, it will *always* be `psi.bisquare`, even if you specify otherwise.